# SQL query to update field only if it is empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automation, upsert

I need to run a query which updates a target DE with some rows from another. There is a field called 'origin' which shows on the target data extension where the data came from.

I appreciate this may be more of a generic SQL query but given Marketing Cloud's limited implementation of SQL and some functions being unavailable, I thought I'd ask here...

Basically it will be updating records in the target data extension based on the primary key (subscriber key). Some data exists on various source data extensions. I only want it to fill in the 'origin' field with a value if the field in the target DE is empty/null. If it already has a value in it, I want it left as it is.

I looked at case statements but could only find examples where the decision was made based on a value being in the source DE, rather than the target DE.

For example, I have the current DE:

| SubscriberKey | Audience |
| --- | --- |
| abc | APP21 |
| xyz |  |

I'm running queries that pick records up from various DEs and there will be duplication. I'd like to run a query that updated the blank value in the xyz record with 'APP20', but I do not want to overwrite the abc record's 'APP21' value with 'APP20'.

Comment: Please update your question to include some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: By DE you mean Data Extensions?

Comment: @codeulike yes.

Answer (score 0):

If the sole purpose of your query is to update the 'origin' field, then you can use **NOT IN** statement of SQL with nested query.

for example

```
SELECT 
      SubscriberKey,
      field1,
      field2,
      ..
      fieldN
FROM SourceDE
WHERE SubscriberKey NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberKey
                            FROM TargetDE
                            WHERE origin IS NOT NULL)
```

This will exclude the subscribers whose 'origin' field is not null/empty from theresult set. As long as you are updating the target DE based on a particular SubscriberKey, only intended rows will be updated.

Hope this helps.